# I am trying to create basic datatables.net and coldfusion server side example but it doesnt seem to works

Tags: datatables, coldfusion, server-side

This example was based on this link 
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40613/datatable-jquery-server-side-with-adobe-cold-fusion-and-sql-server

and i am using datatable version 1.10

On first page load, all data sucessfully loaded into #formsTable
But it wont work when clicking sorting,searching and paging.
 
It just hang with 'processing..'

pageA.cfm (only show scripting part here...)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('#formsTable').DataTable({
        processing:true,
        serverSide:true,
        ajax:{
           url:'pageB.cfm'
        },  
        columns:[
                {title: "id",data:'id'},
                {title: "Name",data:'name'},
                {title: "Emp.No",data:'empno'},
                {title: "IC",data:'ic'}
            ]

        })
   })
</script>
```

pageB.cfm (server-side)

```
<cfcontent reset="true">

<cfset listColumns = "id,emp_no,emp_name,number_id2" />

<cfset sIndexColumn = "id" />

<cfparam name="draw" default="1" type="integer" />

<cfparam name="start" default="0" type="integer" />

<cfparam name="length" default="10" type="integer" />

<cfparam name="url.sSearch" default="" type="string" />

<cfparam name="url.iSortingCols" default="0" type="integer" />

<!--- query data --->
<cfquery datasource="hrms" name="qFiltered">
    select id,emp_no,emp_name,number_id2 from employee
    <cfif len(trim(url.sSearch))>
        Where
        (
        <cfloop list="#listColumns#" index="thisColumn">
          <cfif thisColumn neq listFirst(listColumns)>
          OR
          </cfif>
          #thisColumn# LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="%#trim(url.sSearch)#%" />
        </cfloop>
        )
    </cfif>

    <cfif url.iSortingCols gt 0>
    ORDER BY
    <cfloop from="0" to="#url.iSortingCols-1#" index="thisS">
      <cfif thisS is not 0>, </cfif>
        #listGetAt(listColumns,(url["iSortCol_"&thisS]+1))#
      <cfif listFindNoCase("asc,desc",url["sSortDir_"&thisS]) gt 0>
        #url["sSortDir_"&thisS]#
      </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    </cfif>

</cfquery>

<!--- query data count --->
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="qCount">
    SELECT COUNT(#sIndexColumn#) as total
    FROM qFiltered
</cfquery>

<!--- Output --->
{"draw": <cfoutput>#val(draw)#</cfoutput>,
"recordsTotal": <cfoutput>#qCount.total#</cfoutput>,
"recordsFiltered": <cfoutput>#qFiltered.recordCount#</cfoutput>,
"aaData": [
<cfoutput query="qFiltered" startrow="#val(start+1)#" maxrows="#val(length)#">

<cfif currentRow gt (start+1)>,</cfif>
{
"id":#SerializeJSON(qFiltered.currentrow)#,
"name":#SerializeJSON(qFiltered.emp_name)#,
"empno":#SerializeJSON(qFiltered.emp_no)#,
"ic":
<cfif trim(qFiltered.number_id2) neq '[empty string]'>
#SerializeJSON(qFiltered.number_id2)#
<cfelse>
""
</cfif>
}
</cfoutput> ] }
```

I am stuck here , it seems that something is missing on pageB.cfm ?

Edited:
thanks for @user12031119 pointing out that sent parameter from pageA.cfm to pageB.cfm is different now with v1.10, so basically these parameters should be change :-

sEcho : draw 
iDisplayStart : start 
iDisplayLength : length 
iTotalRecords : recordsTotal 
iTotalDisplayRecords : recordsFiltered

with that change i can now click on next/prev page (paging) but still search and sorting dont work

Comment: You need to look into `SerializeJSON(qFiltered, "struct")`. It is a much quicker way to build JSON data. Also use Postman to see if the data is coming out as expected.

Comment: there is no error on json format data, it can load and fill table with data on first page load

Comment: Never trust client provided data. That kind of dynamic sql is vulnerable to sql injection. See http://www.learncfinaweek.com/course/index/section/Security/item/Injection .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OK finally it works now.** 
So this is it, basic datatables.net coldfusion/lucee server side example.
**Datatables Version 1.10.xx**
**Language Coldfusion/lucee**

pageA.cfm (scripting)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('#formsTable').DataTable({
        processing:true,
        serverSide:true,
        ajax:{
           url:'pageB.cfm',
           type :'post'
        },  
        columns:[
                {title: "id",data:'id'},
                {title: "Name",data:'name'},
                {title: "Emp.No",data:'empno'},
                {title: "IC",data:'ic'}
            ],
        language: {
            infoEmpty: "No records available",
        }

        })
   })
</script>
```

pageB.cfm

```
<cfcontent reset="true">
<cfset listColumns = "id,emp_no,emp_name,number_id2" />
<cfset sIndexColumn = "id" />
<cfparam name="draw" default="1" type="integer" />
<cfparam name="start" default="0" type="integer" />
<cfparam name="length" default="10" type="integer" />
<cfparam name="search" default="" type="string" />

<cfif len(form["search[value]"]) gt 0>
    <cfset search=form["search[value]"]>
</cfif>

<!--- Data set after filtering --->
<cfquery datasource="hrms" name="qFiltered">
select id,emp_no,emp_name,number_id2 from employee
<cfif len(trim(search))>
where
    ( 
    <cfloop list="#listColumns#" index="thisColumn">
    <cfif thisColumn neq listFirst(listColumns)> 
    OR 
    </cfif>
    #thisColumn# LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="%#trim(search)#%" />    
    </cfloop>
    )
</cfif>
<cfif form["order[0][column]"] gt 0>
    ORDER BY 
    <cfif form["order[0][column]"] eq '1'>
    emp_name <cfif form["order[0][dir]"] eq 'desc'>desc</cfif>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form["order[0][column]"] eq '2'>
    emp_no <cfif form["order[0][dir]"] eq 'desc'>desc</cfif>
    </cfif>
    <cfif form["order[0][column]"] eq '3'>
    number_id2 <cfif form["order[0][dir]"] eq 'desc'>desc</cfif>
    </cfif>    
</cfif>
</cfquery>

<!--- Total data set length --->
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="qCount">
SELECT COUNT(#sIndexColumn#) as total
FROM   qFiltered
</cfquery>

<cfif qFiltered.recordcount gt 0>
    <cfset recordsTotal=#qCount.total#>
<cfelse>
    <cfset recordsTotal=0>
</cfif>

<!---
Output
--->

{"draw": <cfoutput>#val(draw)#</cfoutput>,
"recordsTotal": <cfoutput>#recordsTotal#</cfoutput>,
"recordsFiltered": <cfoutput>#qFiltered.recordCount#</cfoutput>,
"data": 
<cfif qFiltered.recordcount gt 0>
[
<cfoutput query="qFiltered" startrow="#val(start+1)#" maxrows="#val(length)#">
    <cfif currentRow gt (start+1)>,</cfif>
    { 
        "id":#SerializeJSON(qFiltered.currentrow)#,
        "name":#SerializeJSON(qFiltered.emp_name)#,
        "empno":#SerializeJSON(qFiltered.emp_no)#,
        "ic":
        <cfif trim(qFiltered.number_id2) neq '[empty string]'>
        #SerializeJSON(qFiltered.number_id2)#
        <cfelse>
        ""
        </cfif>
    }
</cfoutput> ]
<cfelse>
    ""
</cfif>
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately the code sample you're viewing on datatables.net is for legacy datatables.  Under datatables 1.10.x, you will have to use the upgraded keys which version 1.10 expects in your returned json structure.  It looks like you already updated pageA.cfm with the new parameters, however you also need to update your server-side return parameters in pageB.cfm.

Here's a guide to upgrade to version 1.10 https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10

Here's a guide for the new parameters for server-side 1.10 https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

### Edit 1 thanks to James A Mohler

### Edit 2 per issue noticed by myself

Apparently I was mistaken that datatables only accepts an array of arrays when returned from the server.  Apparently it also accepts an array of structs, which helps simplify my answer.  However, this will require aliasing the columns in the select statement to match the column definitions defined in pageA.cfm.  With that said, here are the changes needed.

The first code modification to pageB.cfm will be to alias the columns in your select statemen to match their definition in pageA.cfm.

```
<cfquery datasource="hrms" name="qFiltered">
    select id as id, emp_no as empno, emp_name as name, number_id2 as ic from employee
```

Once that's done, change the following in your `<cfoutput>` block from pageB.cfm

- Change `sEcho` to `draw`
- Change `iTotalRecords` to `recordsTotal`
- Change `iTotalDisplayRecords` to `recordsFiltered`
- Change `aaData` to `data`
- Use `serializeJson()` with the "struct" option to return an array of structs with the key values matching up to how you defined them in pageA.cfm.  If you're using ACF instead of lucee, then you might have to change your column definitions in pageA.cfm to uppercase since ACF doesn't preserve case and uppercases key names.

---

```
<!--- Output --->
<cfoutput>
{
    "draw": #val(url.sEcho)#,
    "recordsTotal": #qCount.total#,
    "recordsFiltered": #qFiltered.recordCount#,
    "data": #serializeJson(qFiltered, "struct")# 
}
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: `serializeJson(qFiltered, "row").data` seems strange. doesn't serialzieJSON() produce string, not a struct?

Comment: Yes @JamesAMohler , you're correct.  Let me make that correction to the code.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I edited this again which simplified my earlier answer.

Comment: ok i edited based on your suggestion but now on first page it just load all data at once not 10 data per page anymore. Sorting and searching are still not working

Comment: i dont think that the returned json data is at wrong here because it successfully loaded on the first page calling. The main issue here is that, after all data loaded into table, all function like search, sort and paging dont work. Nothing happend.

Comment: @AhmadZuwari, you can disregard the `serializeJson()` approach I provided.  However, the other items I mentioned with the new keys do need to be applied for your code to work with datatables 1.10.x.

Comment: thanks user12031119, it seems to work now since i change this sEcho-->draw, iTotalRecords-->recordsTotal , iTotalDisplayRecords-->recordsFiltered , iDisplayStart-->start, iDisplayLength--> length , but what about 'sSearch' and 'iSortingCols' ?

Answer (score 1):

First, check that your JSON output is valid (jsonlint.com)
Then, wrap your JSON output into a cfsavecontent:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="json">
    <cfoutput>
     your output here
    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Then use this code to return the JSON:

```
<cfset lastModDate = DateFormat(Now(),'ddd, dd mmm YYYY') & ' ' & TimeFormat(DateConvert('local2Utc', Now()), 'HH:mm:ss') & ' GMT'> 
<cfheader name="Expires" value="#DateAdd('m', -1, Now())#">
<cfheader name="Last-Modified" value="#lastModDate#">
<cfheader name="cache-control" value="must-revalidate">
<cfheader name="Pragma" value="no-cache">
<cfcontent type="text/x-json" />
<cfoutput>#json#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks. This issue already solved. Its not about json format.